# Is there any canon information about the state of the galaxy by the time of “The Force Awakens”?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

I've read some information on the net about the

> Rebel Alliance still being rebels during the time of *The Force Awakens*, and the Empire still being big.

But today I read in a report about

> The upcoming (and thus canon) battlefront that the new Republic is fighting the Imperial remnants.

So my question here is: is there any canon information out already on what the state of the galaxy is or will be?

Comment: No there isn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not yet, but there will be.

[Journey to Star Wars: The Force Awakens](http://www.starwars.com/news/journey-to-star-wars-the-force-awakens-publishing-program-coming-fall-2015) is an umbrella title for a coming series of publications that will fill in the gap between Episode VI and Episode VII.

> All titles published under Journey to Star Wars: The Force Awakens will be canonical within the Star Wars universe, and in-continuity with the Star Wars films, animated series, new books, and Marvel comics.

The first publication under this banner is scheduled to be the novel [Aftermath](http://www.starwars.com/news/what-happened-after-endor-find-out-in-star-wars-aftermath):

> Aftermath will be the first book in a trilogy that begins to bridge the Star Wars timeline between Return of the Jedi and The Force Awakens ..... I can’t wait for our first canon glimpse into the state of the galaxy after the Battle of Endor.

This passage also confirms that *Aftermath* is going to the the *first* canon material bridging the timeline, so until it's released we have nothing.

Comment: Thanks there  so that means at least september to wait for (as that book is due in september according to the linkned site).

Answer (score 2):

From the recent (on-going?) 2015 Star Wars Celebration, we know a little.  The Rebels are now

> called the Resistance.

Meanwhile, the Empire, or at least the faction that we'll see in *Episode 7* are

> called the First Order.

There will have been post-*Return of the Jedi* a huge battle in the skies above the planet

> Jakku between the Rebel and Empire forces.  This is the source of the destroyed ships on the surface of a desert planet, that planet isn't Tatooine, it's Jakku.

Here's a [link](http://www.theverge.com/2015/4/17/8439411/star-wars-episode-vii-force-awakens-resistance-first-order) that summarizes what we know regarding the names of the factions, and guesses at the rest.  Here's [a link](http://www.theverge.com/2015/4/17/8438973/star-wars-battlefront-connect-return-of-the-jedi-force-awakens) that explains the planet.

<sub>Of course, JJ Abrams swore for months that Khan was *not* in *Star Trek Into Darkness*, so who knows?</sub>